# Magento Sample Data on already installed magento

Tags: magento-1.8, sample-data

**Just a simple question here.** I am using **XAMPP(from Bitnami)** and as you might know bitnami also  provides magento installation, so i downloaded that exe file and installed magento. Now what i want is to make a tech e-commerce website but i am totally new to this and thus i was watching these [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nSxq-eJ0VvY&list=PL3B0BAAF482B16EAB) videos.

**So here is my question:** I was wondering that if i could just install that sample data into my current system and just take it out when i am done. But i do not prefer installing, re-installing and uninstalling as because the last time i installed magento (from bitnami) it didn't work so i needed to re-install and this time it luckily did so i do not want to mess it up. So what is the best option available to me?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to change the database that Magento uses after it has been installed. So the steps for your scenario would be:

1. install sample data into a separate database
2. copy the product images into your Magento installation
3. edit app/etc/local.xml and change the database to the one with the sample data present
4. delete var/cache
5. opening the site in the browser should now trigger the installation routine and you will end up with a store including the demo data

Uninstalling the sample data is not easily doable. You can delete all products which gets you some of the way there. However overall I would suggest keeping the store with the sample data separate. If you don't mind the product images from the demo store clogging up your system you can reverse step 3. and then deleting the cache to get back to your original database.

Answer (score 1):

The sample data provided by Magento must be installed before you complete the Magento installation. It cannot be installed afterwards "out of the box".

Once the sample data is installed, it cannot be uninstalled automatically. You can of course remove elements via the admin backend, but there is no easy way to remove the data completely from a store.

Your best bet is to install Magento with the sample data from the beginning:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-installing#install-sample

and then configure your store from that point, removing elements and settings as needed for your particular needs.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that Don't use this type of Automation tool for Professional level.If you are beginner then it ok. you can use this for improving your knowledge.

you can use latest Community version which will provide by the Magento and the process is set up in local it's very easy.

You can use any server Best is Apache server with Linux OS.

Comment: Hey Keyul, i think you misunderstood me. First of all what do you mean my 'this type of Automation tool' which what?
and why are you telling me about the servers..? :P